# Extracting fixed number of IMFs using EMD

Tags: audio

I am doing a project on audio watermarking via Empirical Mode Decomposition. I have to decompose the signal into IMFs, embed watermark into the last IMF and reconstruct the signal at the sender end. At the receiver end, I have to decompose the signal into IMFs using EMD, extract the watermark. For this to be done successfully, I have to get same number of IMFs in sender and receiver end while decomposing the frame using EMD. I accomplished it by setting the maximum iterations to number of IMFs obtained in sender end, but I didnt find the extraction results satisfactory. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

EMD is very sensitive to the "noise model". More over it does not have an inverse transform (i.e. "empirical"). So at least you have to build a lot of redundancy in your signal.

Answer (score 0):

By default EMD keeps on decomposing signal unless it gets the trend (trend is different from residue), so it may be possible that train & test data may have different properties (volatility etc) thus different number of IMFs will generate.

As a suggestion, i will advise you to use (max_imf: ) this is an optional argument in PyEMD and it may restrict the decomposition to same numbers in train & test data.